# Create excel async function

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, user-defined-functions, excel-addins

I have an excel function that get's data from the internet. The problem is that the function takes a long time to execute and it slows down everything.

**It will be amazing if I can change the value of the cell without changing its formula!** So if I call the function `=GetNumOfEmployee()` that returns 0 imediately and then from my addin when I get the result I can replace the value of that cell with 100 for example. If I do that the fomula gets lost and I do not want that to happen.

What I did in order to preserve the formula was to change the formatting of the cell by doing:

```
this.Application.ActiveCell.NumberFormat = 5;
```

if the active cell had a 0, then that line of code will replace the value to a 5 which is very cool. I get to preserve the formula and I have a new value.

The problem with that approach is that I get a lot of calculations and every time I write the line:

```
this.Application.ActiveCell.NumberFormat = 1234;
```

excel saves that formating at:

[image]

and very soon I reach the maximum number of formatings that excel enables. In 1 minute that list has about 500 formats and soon I am not able to delete them. If I programatically delete them excel acts kind of slow and I get the windows spining mouse icon every time I delete a format.

**So in short I will like to replace the value of a cell without changing its' formula from my addin once I have the result that I need back**. Should I place the value to the right of the cell?

Comment: If you're using custom formats to display the results, what purpose does the formula serve?

Comment: Inside that formula I have `Application.Volatile` that makes the function execute every time the sheet changes. Take for instance the excel function `=Rand()` That function get's executed every time there is a change on the active wroksheet. It is very diferent than regular UDF funcs. But the function I am creating takes a long time to execute so I want to execute again every time a cell changes just like the rand function will have done. If I replace the value of the cell removing the formula then the next time I update the sheet it's value will not be updated. Hope I explain myself correctly

Comment: I'm not sure how many functions you have, or what determines exactly what information gets queried from the web, but one alternate approach would be to have your function first check a global "cache" which could contain the "current" value for that cell: when your query completes it can update that cache with the final value.  E.g. a dictionary with the cell address as the key: the function first checks this object to see if there's a value there - if there is then it just returns the value, if not then it populates "pending" flag and kicks off the query process (final result goes to cache)

Comment: Apparently there's a way to get rid of unused styles. See [You receive a "Too many different cell formats" error message in Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213904) and the suggested resolution in [XLStylesTool](http://sergeig888.wordpress.com/2011/03/21/net4-0-version-of-the-xlstylestool-is-now-available/). However, you can update the formula directly by using the `.Formula` method for a cell (as in `Sheet1.Cells(1,3).Formula` for the formula in cell C3). Then you can use `InStr` to find the location of something you wish to change...